# typescript TSC error: underscore/inde x"' has no exported member '_'

Tags: typescript

my code:

```
'use strict';

import {_ as underscore} from 'underscore';
```

when i import package "underscore", there is one TSC error like this:

```
app/util/global.ts(7,10): error TS2305: Module '"F:/newVRMMO/node_modules/@types/underscore/index"' has no exported member '_'.
```

underscore/index.d.ts:

```
declare var _: _.UnderscoreStatic;
export = _;
export as namespace _;

declare global {
    interface Element { }
}

declare module _ {

    interface ThrottleSettings {
        leading?: boolean;
        trailing?: boolean;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

i don't konw why this error appeared.

this is the package.json:
[image: package.json]

Comment: Did you installed the types? Can you share the package.json?

Comment: @Robert thank you for your reply,yeah,i had installed the types,the package.json is too many code so i post a picture.

Answer (score 2):

sorry，it is my fault, the import is wrong:

```
import {_ as underscore} from 'underscore';
```

the right way to import is:

```
import * as underscore from 'underscore';
```